# interate through nested json file using ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So I have a json file with nested elements. This is my json file:

```
    [
{
    "qid": "1",
    "contester": "0",
    "answer": "0",
    "question": "What are you most likely to do after getting into an argument? ",
    "images": [
        {
            "qid": "1",
            "imageid": "AB100",
            "imgname": "doghug_q1",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q1\/doghug_q1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "1",
            "imageid": "AB101",
            "imgname": "eq_q1.jpg",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q1\/eat_q1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "1",
            "imageid": "AB102",
            "imgname": "headache_q1",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q1\/headache_q1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "1",
            "imageid": "AB106",
            "imgname": "scream_q1.jpg",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q1\/scream_q1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "1",
            "imageid": "AB107",
            "imgname": "shopping_q1",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q1\/shopping_q1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "1",
            "imageid": "AB108",
            "imgname": "walkAlone_q1",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q1\/walkAlone_q1.jpg"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "qid": "2",
    "contester": "0",
    "answer": "0",
    "question": "Which game would you rather play?",
    "images": [
        {
            "qid": "2",
            "imageid": "AB105",
            "imgname": "charades_q2.jpg",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q2\/charades_q2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "2",
            "imageid": "AB109",
            "imgname": "playingCards_q2.jpg",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q2\/playingCards_q2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "2",
            "imageid": "AB110",
            "imgname": "chess_q2",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q2\/chess_q2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "qid": "2",
            "imageid": "AB111",
            "imgname": "twister_q2",
            "imgpath": "Images\/Q2\/twister_q2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

And this is my controller that i used to access the json :

```
   var app= angular.module('myApp', []);

   app.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('results.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.questions = data; // get data from json
          angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(item){
               console.log(item.images);  
           })
        });


    });

  }
]);
```

And then my html code to display the questions and each questions list of images using the ng-repeat :

```
        <body ng-app="myApp" >
          <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
           <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="question in questions"> {{question.qid}} </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
       </body>
```

As of now iam trying to display the questions id from the json file as a list however the output im getting is a:

- {{question.qid}}

as the output in my html page.. Can someone please help me. I dont know what im doing wrong.

Comment: `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);` ?

Comment: `app.controller(/* ... */)` where is `app` defined?

Comment: yes i missed that out. I have added the var app = as you mentioned but the code still doesnt work ..

Comment: try mine, it is working !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has some missing things.

Here is working example of your code

http://plnkr.co/edit/FvD26TYZ9v8TbgUBUzN2?p=preview

firstly,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); //variable app is missing.
```

**secondly, data you mention has missing closing square brace.**

Answer (score 0):

You haven's define the `app` so you should change the first line of your code to this and check your closing tags on your js code...:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.questions = [];

    $http.get('results.json').success(function(data) {

        $scope.questions = data; // get data from json

        angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(item){
            console.log(item.images);  
        })

    });
}

]);
```

Comment: Still doesnt seem to be working.. the question ids from the json doesnt show up in the html

Comment: Yes!! I get a: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at http://localhost:8012/questionnaire.php:112:11 ... this is where my :  <li ng-repeat="question in questions"> {{question.qid}} </li> line is.

Comment: Did import angular to your project through a cdn or somewhere? Please update your question with your full HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Complete working code for your case :

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="question in questions"> {{question.qid}} </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);

 app.controller('ListCtrl',function ($scope,$http) {
   $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.questions = data; // get data from json
    });
 });
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PRA6vWHzISZ0mJTHmks8?p=preview)

It is working !! Try once !!

Answer (score 0):

First define `app`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Then initiate your `$scope.questions` on your controller like

```
$scope.questions = [];
```

Also you might need to parse your `data` with

```
$scope.questions = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: I have done the changes you have mentioned. but it still doesnt seem to be working :/

Comment: @Y.Hewa could you provide a fiddle or something similar?